# Xarray - daily averages from hourly data in multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x, netcdf, python-xarray

I have 5 netCDF files with moored current meters data. Each file looks like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (BINDEPTH: 50, INSTRDEPTH: 3, LATITUDE: 5, LONGITUDE: 5, TIME: 44106)
Coordinates:
* INSTRDEPTH  (INSTRDEPTH) float64 100.0 280.0 600.0
* LATITUDE    (LATITUDE) float64 -34.04 -33.8 -33.67 -33.56 -33.51
* LONGITUDE   (LONGITUDE) float64 27.57 27.59 27.64 27.72 27.86
* TIME        (TIME) datetime64[ns] 2015-04-11T15:00:00 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: BINDEPTH
Data variables:
PRES        (TIME, INSTRDEPTH) float32 dask.array<shape=(44106, 3), chunksize=(44106, 3)>
VCUR        (TIME, BINDEPTH) float32 dask.array<shape=(44106, 50), chunksize=(44106, 50)>
UCUR        (TIME, BINDEPTH) float32 dask.array<shape=(44106, 50), chunksize=(44106, 50)>
WCUR        (TIME, BINDEPTH) float32 dask.array<shape=(44106, 50), chunksize=(44106, 50)>
ECUR        (TIME, BINDEPTH) float32 dask.array<shape=(44106, 50), chunksize=(44106, 50)>
```

I am trying to plot vertical sections of the data i.e `plt.contourf(distance,BINDEPTH,VCUR)`

I am able to do this with specific timestamps but I am struggling with creating daily averages and plotting the results.

Here is an example of what im expecting:
[image]

To create daily averages I have tried:

```
data2 = data.resample(TIME='1D').mean('TIME')
data3 = data2.sel(TIME='2015-6-15')
```

This produces:[image]

It seems to be averaging both over position and time, so how do I average over time only?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you plotted? data2 or data3. If data3, then it is supposed to look like the image you have as it is only for one day...

Comment: @msi_gerva Iv plotted data3, The data shouldn't change that drastically between each hourly timestamp, so id expect a similar result to the first plot. Perhaps I need to pad each file with nan's to ensure all time and space dimensions are the same. sorry I'm quite new to this.

Comment: I guess the data itself could help other to solve the problem...

Comment: Unfortunately the file's are quite big so I wont be able to share them.

Comment: In your original Dataset (before resampling or plotting) it seems that `VCUR` only has dimensions `TIME` and `BINDEPTH`.  Should there also be a dimension representing the distance offshore?  I think your call to resample and selection of a given day looks correct, but perhaps the distance dimension was lost sometime earlier?

Comment: @spencerkclark I'v calculated the distance from the latitude and longitudes from the netcdf files.

Comment: @jetman can you show how you obtained your expected plot?

Comment: @spencerkclark, Iv realized the `resample` is correct. For the expected plot I didn't have to `meshgrid` (x,y,z were all 50x5) where as the daily averaged data `VCUR` is a single dimension so I gridded it with distance to get the same dimensions. That must be where the issue is.

Comment: @jetman great!  Indeed for the daily averaged case in your example it makes sense that to obtain a filled contour plot of `VCUR` along depth and distance you would need to broadcast along a new distance dimension.  In the original case, did you have some way of computing `VCUR` as a function of distance offshore?  My sense is that you should be able to start from that DataArray (presumably having dimensions `TIME`, `BINDEPTH`, and `distance`), resample it, select a day, and plot it to obtain your desired result.

Comment: @spencerkclark That makes sense, I'll give it a go. Thanks very much.